# Xcode 11.4 archive fails when building target dependency

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11.4

I have a framework project which gets build using a shell script under Build Phase. It uses `xcodebuild` to do that. 
Since I have updated the Xcode to 11.4, I am getting the following error when the consuming project tries to build the dependency for above framework( The same works fine when I build the framework on it's own).

> unable to create directory '/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cnatioifembsmzdvoyyuogceigiw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/AppName-Staging/BuildProductsPath/Debug-iphoneos/FrameworkName.framework' (in target 'TargetName' from project 'ProjectName')

I have checked the write permission on the directory. I have given full hard disk access to Xcode under Security and Privacy but it is still happening.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe. Just maybe you don't have enough disk space.

Comment: Don't think so, more than 200 GB available.

Comment: Alright, just an option to check.

Comment: It’s always worth trying to delete the whole derived data folder  for this app, and try again. First close the project and shut down Xcode.

Comment: I have tried deleting the whole derived data, restarting my system just in case.